# Capacitor for 3 minutes off!

Tags: led

I want my led strip lights to turn automatically off after 3 or 5 minutes of turning on.

Please, suggest a very simple circuit using capacitors which would block the circuit and turn off the LEDs continuously after 3 or 5 minutes.

Also, any problems to the capacitors in such case the circuit is blocked by the capacitors for long hours like 2 to 3 hrs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you searched for any solutions? ebay and others sell suitable timer circuits....

Comment: Start here: https://startingelectronics.org/beginners/start-electronics-now/tut2-transistor-timer/

Comment: That simple timer circuit will "work", but for times longer than a few seconds it will not be accurate and the timing may vary a lot with air temperature and glitches in battery voltage, e.g. brake or turn indicator lights coming on. The *reliable* way to generate time delays of minutes or hours is to use an oscillator with a stable frequency and count the number of cycles. If you want to design and make something yourself, use a microcontroller like a PIC or Arduino.

Comment: Need to know supply voltage, current, is this for automotive application...

Comment: 12 v DC and current 2.5 amps max.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NE555 circuit which is very popular and you will find tons of results on Google.

Although, I would suggest to rather use an Arduino, it will be simpler and you can have precise timing and can easily change to any time you want.